# React, how to update state fast

Tags: reactjs

What would be the recommended way to display a rapidly changing value in React, e.g upload progress?  In my axios config I have

```
onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
    let percentCompleted = Math.round( (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total )
    this.setState({ avatarUploadPercentage: percentCompleted })
}
```

`<span>Upload progress: {this.state.avatarUploadProgress}</span>`

but `setState` doesn't like being called that quickly of course, and won't guarantee order. Should I use refs instead and change the inner html myself?

Comment: How many times would that function be called in a second?

Comment: setState() can be called that quickly. There is nothing wrong with that kind of  usage. Of course don't use refs and don't try manipulate the DOM by yourself for that kind of a 'progress' implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about limiting when the `onUploadProgress` callback runs? You can wrap your callback in a "debounce" function which limits the frequency a callback will run. [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) and [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce) offer debounce methods.

Once per second:

```
onUploadProgress: debounce(progressEvent => {
    let percentCompleted = Math.round( (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total )
    this.setState({ avatarUploadPercentage: percentCompleted })
}, 1000)
```

See plain debounce function from https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using a ref to access the element that is displaying the progress. Calling setState for that case is a bit wasteful on the rendering side if it's just a progress bar/value that is changing. Call setState when the upload begins to display progress, then setState again to hide it after it's complete.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do with the value of `avatarUploadPercentage` ? If you need to display the actual number, then as suggested in the other answer you could either debounce setState or modify the dom directly.

However if it's displaying a progress bar being filled, it could be done using CSS, although still modifying the element via ref, but not triggering a whole component lifecycle (wasteful)

Something like

`` [refToProgressBarElement].style.width = `${avatarUploadPercentage}%` ``